# Pre-serializing some fields of a proto message

Tags: c++, optimization, serialization, protocol-buffers

Suppose I have a proto structure that looks like the following:

```
message TMessage {
    optional TDictionary dictionary = 1;
    optional int specificField1 = 2;
    optional TOtherMessage specificField2 = 3;
    ...
}
```

Suppose I am using C++. This is the message stub that is used in the master process to send information to the bunch of the nodes using the network. In particular, the `dictionary` field is 1) pretty heavy 2) common for all the serialized messages, and all the following specific fields are filled with the relatively small information specific to the destination node.

Of course, dictionary is built only once, but it comes out that the major part of running time is spent while serializing the common `dictionary` part again and again for each new node.

Obvious optimization would be to pre-serialize `dictionary` into the byte string and put it into the `TMessage` as a `bytes` field, but this looks a bit nasty to me.

Am I right that there is no built-in way to pre-serialize a message field without ruining the message structure? It sounds like an idea for a good plugin for proto compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Protobuf is designed such that concatenation === composition, at least for the root message. That means that you can serialize an object with *just* the dictionary, and snapshot the bytes somewhere. Now for each of the real messages you can paste down that snapshot, and then serialize an object with *just* the other fields - just whack it straight after: no additional syntax is required. This is semantically identical to serializing them all at the same time. In fact, since it will retain the field order, it should actually be identical bytes too.

It helps that you used "optional" throughout :)

Answer (score 2):

Marc's answer is perfect for your use case. Here is just another option:

1. The field must be a submessage, like your `TDictionary` is.
2. Have another variant of the outer message, with `bytes` in place of the submessage you want to preserialize:

```
    message TMessage_preserialized {
        optional bytes dictionary = 1;
        ...
    }
```

3. Now you can serialize the `TDictionary` separately and put the resulting data in the `bytes` field. In protobuf format, submessages and `bytes` field are written out the same way. This means you can serialize as `TMessage_preserialized` and still deserialize as normal `TMessage`.